# Plot multiple measurements

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data set with 12 individuals measured at 25 time points. I want a graph, which lines ordered by individual (1-12) and measurment (A, B, or C) and the timepoints on the x axis and the value on the y.

The cols of my dataset look like this (so it is already in long format):
Individuum (1 x 25; 2 x 25...) / Measurment (A B or C) / timepoint (1 - 25, 1- 25,...) / value

I already tried this:

```
ggplot(data = Replicate1, mapping = aes(x = Reading, y = value, linetype = Group))
```

but there are no lines showed and I dont know how to add the measurement.

Comment: Use `dput()` with a subset of your data and paste the results into your question. You use `Group` and `Reading` in your code, but they are not mentioned in your description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may do something like this.  Showing you on a sample data.

```r
set.seed(12)
df <- data.frame(individual = rep(1:12, each =3),
           obs = LETTERS[1:3],
           time = rep(1:25, each = 36),
           val = sample(25:100, 900, T))

library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x= time, y = val, group = individual, color = as.factor(individual))) +
  geom_line() +
  facet_wrap(. ~ obs, ncol = 1)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-07-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>